# How to apply a function to a button

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have four drop down lists. Each drop down list has all false values and one true value, and my aim is to produce an alert message and open a new page based on the values being true. However, I would like to know how I can apply this code to a button so that the described action happens when the button is clicked because absolutely nothing happens at the moment.

```
<input name="button" type="submit" class="main" id="button" value="Submit" onclick="submit()" />


</script>

<script type="javascript">
```

This is the details of my button its placed here for your reference:

```
<input name="button" type="submit" class="main" id="button" value="Submit" onclick="submit()" />

var selectbox = document.getElementById("select_box"); 
var a = selectbox.options[selectbox.selectedIndex].value;

var selectbox2 = document.getElementById("select_box2"); 
var b = selectbox2.options[selectbox2.selectedIndex].value;

var selectbox3 = document.getElementById("select_box3"); 
var c = selectbox3.options[selectbox3.selectedIndex].value;

var selectbox4 = document.getElementById("select_box4"); 
var d = selectbox4.options[selectbox4.selectedIndex].value;


if (a == "true" && b == "true" && c == "true" && d == "true")
{
alert("Correct you have won press OK for your Reward!")
document.open("Reward.html");
}
else
{
alert("Not right Please try again!");
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your onClick value points to a function like this:

```
<input name="button" type="submit" class="main" id="button" value="Submit" onclick="checkValues();"/>
```

And the function actually exists:

```
function checkValues(){
var selectbox = document.getElementById("select_box"); 
var a = selectbox.options[selectbox.selectedIndex].value;

var selectbox2 = document.getElementById("select_box2"); 
var b = selectbox2.options[selectbox2.selectedIndex].value;

var selectbox3 = document.getElementById("select_box3"); 
var c = selectbox3.options[selectbox3.selectedIndex].value;

var selectbox4 = document.getElementById("select_box4"); 
var d = selectbox4.options[selectbox4.selectedIndex].value;

if (a == "true" && b == "true" && c == "true" && d == "true")
    {
        alert("Correct you have won press OK for your Reward!")
        document.open("Reward.html");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Not right Please try again!");
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: I still get nothing even when i click on the button, would code for the button need to be actually where all the if statments are or something ?

Comment: Try adding in some alert() statements to see what the problem is. Is the function actually being called? Does the selectbox variable have a value? Also make sure to check JavaScript's error log to get some pointers to what's wrong.